# how to encode json.stringified output

Tags: php, jquery

i have a form to which the form elements are appended using the onclick event.

the form elements along with their values and label are then maintained in an array .

```
function save_form() {
    var x = document.getElementById("formBuilder");
    var elements_data = new Array;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x.elements[i].type == 'checkbox' || x.elements[i].type == 'radio') {
            var all_ele_value = [];
            var ele_id = x.elements[i].id;
            $("input:" + x.elements[i].type + "[name=" + ele_id + "[]]").each(function () {
                all_ele_value.push($(this).val());
            });
            var end_value = all_ele_value.join(";");
        }
        else if (x.elements[i].type == 'select-one') {
            var ele_id = x.elements[i].id;
            var end_value = $("#" + ele_id + " option").map(function (i, n) {
                return n.value;
            }).get().join(";");
        }
        else {
            var end_value = x.elements[i].value;
        }
    }
    var form_data = JSON.stringify(elements_data);
    $.post(software_url + 'form_manager/save_form', {
        'form_data': form_data
    }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

now i want to encode form_data in my php file . I want to know a way to do that because json_decode does not work. Iam getting all the output in json format .BUt i want to iterate through it.

Comment: Can you show a sample string for form_data.

Comment: big problem is you are using `JSON.stringify` on an empty array. `element_data` never gets modified after it is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm strongly going to recommend two things to you.

One is learning about [jQuery.serialize,](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) which does the heavy lifting work you did to put all the elements together in a string.

Moving right along, json_decode does work, unless the JSON string is invalid, check what you are receiving and test it your JSON syntax on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) - to see if it's correct.

In php, you have to use json_decode, and then you can go through it.

```
<?php
$array = json_decode($json_string);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     echo "key: ". $key ." => ". $value;
}
?>
```